# Repeatedly process items in parallel

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a set of items that need to be processed in parallel over and over again.

I can do this:

```
while (true)
{
   Parallel.ForEach(sources, source =>
   {
      // do lots of work with source
   })
}
```

But the problem is, if one source takes far longer than the others, it will effectively hang the while loop and I'd like to reprocess each item in the list without waiting for other items to complete.

How can I accomplish that? Start a task for each source which has it's own while loop or is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Just to clarify, let's assume that you have X tasks that should be processed in parallel, and one hangs, you're allowed to continue to process the other tasks again? Also, clarify why you **need** to process these in parallel. Some background / context to what you're trying to achieve would also help getting the best answer.

Comment: Let's say each task is downloading a file from a source-specific url.I need to repeatedly download the same file for each source over and over again because it keeps changing.

Comment: @powlette Then your work is IO bound, not CPU bound, and you shouldn't be using `Parallel` at all.  You don't need to be creating a bunch of threads just to have all of them sit there doing nothing while you wait for network requests.

Comment: @Servy, that's why web browsers use a single thread and download content one at a time. smh.

Comment: @powlette You don't need to download items one at a time.  You can simply use a single thread to download multiple items at the same time.  Web browsers aren't spinning up hundreds of threads only to have them sit there doing nothing waiting for network requests.  When they're creating additional threads it's because they have CPU bound work for them to do.

Comment: @Servy, TPL doesn't necessarily create threads at all because a task is not always a thread. I simply gave an example of how I could easily process multiple items in parallel to demonstrate the problem of being hung up on one and not being able to loop through again. You're on a tangent to the issue and adding nothing to the solution.

Comment: @powlette I'm well aware that the TPL doesn't necessarily involve the creation of multiple threads.  *You* are the one who tried to poke fun at me for telling you that you don't need multiple threads to perform multiple network requests in parallel.  I said that the `Parallel` class is going to be using multiple threads, because that's what you're using and it *isn't* going to achieve parallelism without using multiple threads.  Yes, it is a tangent, but it's an important one.  Like I said earlier, you shouldn't be spinning up tons of threads just to have them sit there doing nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `ConcurrentQueue` you can quite simply achieve what you're looking for. Providing sample code below:

```
public Task CreateDownloader(ConcurrentQueue<string> queue, CancellationToken token, 
    TimeSpan interval, Action<string, string> continuation)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            string url;
            if (queue.TryDequeue(out url))
            {
                try
                {
                    var result = await MockDownloader.Download(url);
                    continuation(url, result);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // Implement exception handling and logging here.
                    // Optionally, you can also pass in how to handle these.
                }
                queue.Enqueue(url);
            }
            await Task.Delay(interval);
        }
    });
}
```

#### Usage

```
void Main()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cancellationToken = cts.Token;
    var maxConcurrentDownloads = 4;

    var sources = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(
        new[] { "foo", "hanging", "bar" });

    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, maxConcurrentDownloads)
        .Select(_ => CreateDownloader(
            // The list (queue) of URLs
            sources, 
            // Cancellation token for clean shut down
            cancellationToken, 
            // Time between downloads
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), 
            // The action taken for each download
            (string url, string result) => Console.WriteLine($"{url} downloaded")));

    Console.WriteLine("Download commenced, press any key to initiate shutdown");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

#### Using a MockDownload for testing purposes:

```
public static class MockDownloader
{
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    public async static Task<string> Download(string url)
    {
        if (url == "hanging")
            // wait for 5 seconds
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        else
            // wait for 500 to 700 ms
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500 + rnd.Next(0, 200)));

        return $"{url} done";
    }
}
```

---

#### Side note:

This isn't perfect, but it demonstrates how one can use a `ConcurrentQueue` in a way that supports your needs.

Other ways would be to use `IObservable` and `Observable` from the [Reactive Extensions (Rx) library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985(v=vs.103).aspx).

You can also with benefit research [`Dataflow` in the TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx).